# How to add a letsencrypt certificate to a wordpress blog?

Tags: wordpress, ssl, lets-encrypt

I want to use a letsencrypt certificate for my hosted wordpress blog. I've created a letsencrypt certificate using `acme.sh` from one of my root servers. This works well, the certificate has been validated and the certificate is stored in a file on the root server.
What is the next step? How can I add the certificate to wordpress? I don't have access to the httpserver or anything else. 
Btw. the wordpress plugin for ssl didn't work for me because it seems not to work with subdomains.

Comment: No access to the server's configuration = no SSL cert. SSL works on the socket, not on the HTTP Response (that's the only part WP deals with). Ask your host how to add an SSL certificate to their config.